# CKEditor.replace is not using the content of the textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm creating a new editor by using:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( textAreaName );
```

It's replacing the textarea, but the value of the text area (which was set dynamically in javascript) is not showing in the editor.

Prior to creating the editor, I run:

```
textArea.value = "Test value";
textArea.innerHTML = "Test value";
```

But this still does not show in the editor. How do I get the editor to use its value?

Comment: you sure the value is set before the editor initializes? Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl i will do that first chance i get, not at computer right now

Comment: Well textarea's do not have innerHTML so that would not work. Setting value should be fine. You need to show more context.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, i will as soon as I'm in front of computer again

Answer (score 0):

The node was created but not yet added to the document. CKEDITOR cannot create an editor until the source element has been placed into the document.